# How to toggle nano softwrap on mac

Tags: macos, nano

I tried the following recommended approaches unsuccessfully to toggle softwrap in `nano` on MacOS  Catalina:

- I can't do <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> as in the manual, it gives `ß` on my keyboard.
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>S</kbd> gives "Smooth scrolling enabled"
- <kbd>Esc</kbd>-<kbd>$</kbd> gives "Unknown command"

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default `nano` on macOS is release 2.0.6.

Soft line wrapping, enabled via the `-a` command line option or via <kbd>Esc</kbd>+<kbd>$</kbd> inside the editor, [was introduced in release 2.2](https://www.nano-editor.org/history.php).

To install a more recent release of the editor on macOS, use e.g. [Homebrew](https://brew.sh/):

```
brew install nano
```

This would (currently) install `nano` release 4.9.2, which also happens to be the most recent release.